# Differences between import options for 3rd party libraries in typescript/Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, momentjs, angular-cli

What's the difference between:
`import * as jslibname from 'jslibname'`
and 
`declare var jslibname: any;`

For example, for firebase, I need `declare var firebase: any;`
For moment, I need `import * as moment from 'moment';`

What's the logic here? When do I use one or the other?

This is with the Angular CLI and systemjs by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
import * as library from 'library';
```

you are really importing the library and you can start using it. If you try to use it without importing before you would gen en error. Sometimes the library **is being imported already** in some place in your app but you just want to use it. You can, with no issues, and the app will work, but I guess that in your case the TS compiler throws an error (and probably your IDE marks it as an error). This is because there is no typing definition file for your library (.d.ts). The easiest way to fix it is to do

```
declare var library: any;
```

This is telling the TS compiler that library exists and stops throwing an compilation error (also IDE stops complaining).

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thanks! I'll have to take a closer look at my config files next time.